# Convert coordinates in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, graphics

How to convert LayoutParams coordinates `layoutParams.x` and `layoutParams.y` to `android.graphics.Path` coordinates? `path.moveTo(layoutParams.x, layoutParams.y);`